# Shell Script "|| { }" Readable Alternative

Tags: bash, syntax, shell

I was looking for a way to check if a program is installed using Shell Script when I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/126353) which contained this code:

```
hash foo 2>&- || { echo >&2 "I require foo but it's not installed.  Aborting."; exit 1; }
```

But that code isn't very (human) readable, what is the alternative for that syntax?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more clear on what/how you would want to check? Do you want to see if a binary file/name is in your $PATH? Do you want to see if a specific rpm/dpkg is installed in the system? Please explain a little bit more.

Comment: I want to check for binaries file/name on the `$PATH`

Comment: Got it. Then `hash` mentioned below is one alternative, `which` is another. :) And I agree with the others, the code is quite alright, just have to understand it and put a few newlines here and there to make more sense of it. You can strip it quite a bit depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Readability is very subjective. I particularly think the original is very readable, once you know that `||` means a short-circuiting **OR**. So you read the original as "do this, **OR** this if that one fails".

The equivalent code without using `||` is:

```
if ! hash foo 2>&-
then
    echo >&2 "I require foo but it's not installed.  Aborting."
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

that's perfectly readable for anyone accustomed to shell scripts, because it's an idiom.  the only hindrance to readability is the lack of newlines:

```
hash foo 2>&- || {
  echo >&2 "I require foo but it's not installed.  Aborting."
  exit 1
}
```

Comment: Been here two years and still not using any capitalisation?! :(

Comment: i've been like that for much longer.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Perhaps you could spare some effort to use capitalisation here.